# How to Download angular route.js file from angularjs.org in window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to download the angular-route.js from the below link
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute
I am getting the following errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amoZC.png)

Comment: I have to import the file in html file.For that i have to download the file angular-route.js .Please help  me here.I am not getting this.

Answer (score 1):

In the installation section you must replace X.Y.Z with the version of ngRoute you want, like:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular-route.js

Comment: C:\Users\gourav\Desktop\AngularJS\js>npm install --save angular-route 1.7.7
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 1.7.7@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-06T00_04_43_585Z-debug.log

Comment: Try npm install --save angular-route@1.7.7

Comment: After trying with the command npm  install --save angular-route@1.7.7 the errors- npm WARN meanstack@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN meanstack@1.0.0 No repository field..

Comment: After that it is showing that 1 package by name angular-route@1.7.7 is added but not showing in folder where i have added